# Invalidate session followed by redirect recreates the bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, managed-bean, session-scope

Working on a JSF validator method defined in a @SessionScoped bean:

```
public void doValidation(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    // throws ValidatorException on invalid input
    ...
    // But, in some cases we want to lock out the user by invalidating session and redirecting to a different error page
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.invalidateSession();
    ec.redirect(errorPage);
}
```

However, the behavior I am seeing on the redirect is, instead of/ before going to the error page, the @SessionScoped bean seems to be getting recreated (its constructor and @PostConstruct is being called).
When the invalidateSession() call is removed, it directly goes to the errorPage without recreating the bean. Note that, the error page has no references to this bean.

Comment: The redirect is something that needs to be sent to the browser, doing so is just like “reloading -metaphorically” the page you’re actually in, then redirecting, this behavior has to do with your view and how you wrote it.

Comment: I recreated you’re example and the session bean doesn’t get recreated, I blame you’re view code, or something else not the redirect call, please try it minimizing additional code. and don’t forget the IOException for your call, your code doesn’t compile.

Comment: Yes, always create a [mcve]...